# How to properly filter reversed ManyToMany?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I can't figure out how to filter reversed `ManyToMany` in `Django`. I want to get `LanguageLevel` objects, connected with at least one `UserProfile`.

In human: All languages such as at least one User can speak this Language.

---

I have a model:

```
class LanguageLevel(models.Model):
    ...
```

and

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
   language_levels = models.ManyToManyField('LanguageLevel', blank=True, related_name='translators')
    ...
```

Already tried:

```
active_language_levels = LanguageLevel.objects.filter(lambda x: len(x.translators)!=0)
```

AND

```
for language_level in LanguageLevel.objects.all():
        print language_level.translators
        if len(language_level.translators)>0:
            print 'ok'
            print language_level
        else:
            print 'no'
            print language_level
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

LanguageLevel.objects.all() \
                .annotate(translators_count=Count('translators__id')) \
                .filter(translators_count__gte=1)
```

Just add proper link on `translators__id` to count distinct entries of each user.

If you want to select languages for specific user, just pass proper queryset before annotate:

```
LanguageLevel.objects.filter(translators__id=user_id)
                .annotate(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter by a M2M field using django orm. Instead you can follow this workaround,

`LanguageLevel.objects.all().values('language_levels__id')`

Comment: It raises exception, I would inspect the Exception by myself but I totally don't understand how this could work. Exception Value: 
Cannot resolve keyword 'language_levels' into field. Choices are: id, language, language_id, level, level_id, price_multiplier, translators

Comment: Sorry its `UserProfile.objects.all().values('language_levels__id')`

Comment: Oh, yeah, it does make sense. Thank you!